# SQL join returns duplicate results not what is reflected in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables user, product, and userproduct.

User has the user profile information, product has a primary key, and userproduct has two heading for UserId and ProductId which I use to match up which user owns what product.

userproduct is set up in the following way:

```
----------------------------------
| UserId (int) | ProductId (int) |
----------------------------------
| 1           | 1                |
----------------------------------
| 1           | 2                |
----------------------------------
```

my PHP code is as follows:

```
$userId = 1;

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM product join userproduct on product.ProductId = userproduct.UserId where UserId = ?');
$stmt->execute([$userId]);
$products = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($products as $productsOwned)
{
    echo $productsOwned['ProductName'];
}
```

I would assume this would  echo out *Product1, Product2.* However, it echos out *Product1, Product1.*

I've looked over my database a few times and everything seems in order, but as I am still learning SQL I assume I have made a mistake there. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL is wrong, If you want to join this tables and get all the user products you can do this:

```
SELECT userproduct.UserId as userId, product.name as productName
FROM userproduct
JOIN product ON userproduct.ProductId = product.ProductId
WHERE userproduct.UserID = {$userId};
```

Comment: I think you have a type in `product.name` which I assumed you meant `product.productName` so I changed that in my code but now I get the following error: `Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 40` and line 40 is: `echo $productsOwned['ProductName'];`

Comment: Try to var_dump the results ($products) and let me know what you get in there

Comment: I get: `array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["userId"]=> int(1) ["productName"]=> string(9) "Product1" } [1]=> array(2) { ["userId"]=> int(1) ["productName"]=> string(13) "Product2" } }`

Comment: You are getting the right response, You should double check your code. If you take your response and do `echo $products[0]["productName"];` you should get `Product1`

Comment: I see my mistake, you put `as productName` but I was still referencing it as `ProductName` in my array, once I changed it to the correct one it worked, thank you.